# How to deal with a negative resistor in Z parameters of a passive network?

Tags: circuit-analysis, theory, circuit-theory

This question is so basic but for some reason I am not seeing it: Assume an arbitrary passive 2-port network having only isotropic materials. This implies S21=S21 and Z12=Z21 (see https://www.microwaves101.com/encyclopedias/basic-network-theory and https://www.rfcafe.com/references/electrical/s-h-y-z.htm).

From https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impedance_parameters#Two-port_networks:

[image]

This could be a classical passive T network, for example. Fully passive means it should (at least at one frequency) be possible to describe it with real components (nonnegative resistors, capacitors, inductors).

Consider the following circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fNcspC.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

At 915 MHz, it is easy to verify that that Z12=Z21=-3.75-j112 Ohm. Why is Z12 negative and how to build the proper passive two-port network that's actually reliazable?

Comment: Did you skip the step where you picked an operating frequency? Without doing that, I don't see how you determined the numerical value of the Z parameters.

Comment: Yes, sorry skipped that. I use f=915MHz. Will add it.

Comment: Have you tried simulating that circuit and see what the input impedance is at 915 MHz? It's easy to do.

Comment: "having only isotropic elements" What exactly do you mean by that sentence? please explain it in detail or include a link to something that does. The same goes for "this implies reciprocity (Z12=Z21)". Neither of those sentences make any sense to me and I can't find anything (by googling) which uses those terms. Also you don't show Z21 anywhere, it is impossible to know which impedance you think is Z21. To me it feels a lot like you have got very little understanding of the theory behind two-port networks, and that you have gotten some basic concepts mixed up. You need to elaborate A LOT.

Comment: @Andy aka: Yes I did (it’s resistive-capacitive). In fact, the circuit comes from a large (fully passive) LTspice simulation. I just stripped it down to the minimum while still preserving Re(Z12) < 0.

Comment: The point is that it doesn't produce negative resistance in the simulation yes?

Comment: @Andyaka: well, the T-network has. The actual circuit is just shown as an example (it’s a black box, could be from a measurement too). I was thinking that every passive network can be represented as T-network (at least at one frequency) and this T-network would strictly consist of realizable impedances (combinations of R,L,C since the actual circuit is linear and passive). Apparently this is just not the case.

Comment: PS: I should have redrawn the T-network just using resistors and capacitors (in series) to make it clear there is a negative R (and C)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About the negative resistance and reactance of the transfer impedance in a passive network:

That's no problem. It doesn't claim that a resistor has negative resistance, it claims that the output voltage in port 2 has quite much phase lag when compared to input current in port 1, about 182 degrees at 915 MHz. That's nothing special in transmission lines or complex enough RLC networks.

Your problematic Z21 is well realizable at 915 MHz. You can find the needed circuit in your question just below words "Consider the following circuit" (checked it with a circuit analysis program).

I am sure that at single frequency equivalent passive T-network where Z21 is a single component or one port circuit cannot be built because it would need a negative resistor which needs some amplifying component. But nobody has claimed it can be built, it only obeys the same equations and to be able to do it and to be at the same time a T-network a negative resistor is a must.

BTW the assumption of the existence of certain circuit leads easily to a need of non-existent parts or the assumption itself contains a contradiction. A brutal example: "The resistor that should be inserted in series with a 2 Ohm resistor to get total 1 Ohm resistance".

A little more complex example: "The  Perfect Future Predictor".  It has an opamp and a delay line as negative feedback, its transfer function is perfect time shift (=the delay time) from the future to now. It doesn't have nonexistent parts but it's based on false assumption the circuit is stable.

Comment: Thanks. So is the answer to the question: “Any passive, reciprocal two-port can be represented with the T network shown above. However, in this representation the circuit may be unrealizable.” ? And “Nothing about a circuit can be inferred from the fact that Re(Z21) < 0” ?

Comment: I checked it. Re(Z21) is negative. No negative resistors are needed for that thing, the  182 degree phase lag is enough. So, no problem with Re( Z21)<0. A realizable passive T-network with Re(Z21)<0 which is constructed so that Z21 is a single component or one port circuit doesn't exist because negative resistance needs active components.